# Renaming "Areas" folder in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to rename Areas folder? Will visual studio and razor find correct path to views in this case ?

Comment: As long as you update namespace and route references to the Areas folder

Answer (score 3):

Yes it's possible! Let's make things easy focusing on the task of renaming an area from Foo to Bar.

1. Rename the area folder Foo to Bar
2. The area folder must contain a file which name ends in AreaRegistration.cs. Rename it from FooAreaRegistration.cs to BarAreaRegistration.cs. *(current step is not mandatory but helps to keep your code clean)*
3. Edit the file BarAreaRegistration.cs from:

   ```
   public override string AreaName 
   {
      get 
      {
          return "Foo";
      }
   }

   public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
   {
       context.MapRoute(
          "Foo_default",
          "Foo/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
          new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
      );
   }
   ```

   to:

   ```
   public override string AreaName 
   {
      get 
      {
          return "Bar";
      }
   }

   public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
   {
       context.MapRoute(
          "Bar_default",
          "Bar/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
          new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
      );
   }
   ```
4. Rename also the namespace of the class from namespace xxxxx.Foo to xxxxx.Bar
5. Replace the namespace for every controller inside the Bar folder
6. Replace Foo with Bar in Views when needed (usually you get an absolute path when using specific area layout

Tested MVC > 4.0

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to rename Areas folder in MVC. This is the location where Razor View Engine looks for Area Views. Add the following code in the Global.asax file. Now View Engine will search Area Views in the location ~/Modules/HelloArea/Views/Hello/Index.cshtml  instead of ~/Areas/HelloArea/Views/Hello/Index.cshtml

```
RazorViewEngine viewEngine = new RazorViewEngine();
viewEngine.AreaMasterLocationFormats =
viewEngine.AreaPartialViewLocationFormats =
viewEngine.AreaViewLocationFormats =
        new string[] {
    "~/Modules/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
    "~/Modules/{2}/Views/Shared/{1}/{0}.cshtml"};
ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(viewEngine);
```